# Conditional fill dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-science

I am fairly new to pandas so bear with me. I have a dataframe with interaction-data (begin time of the interaction, end time of the interaction, userA and userB that had interaction):

> begin, end, userA, userB.

Now I would like to transform this data into the following format (time from 0 to x, userId of one user, a boolean value yes or no if there was an interaction).

> time, userId, interaction.

I saw some posts about conditional dataframes using np.where but I am not yet sure how to stick this together. I am sorry for not providing a code-example.

Example:
(input):

```
begin, end, userA, userB

130,     300, 1, 2
```

(output):

```
time, user, interaction

...

130, 1, yes

130, 2, yes

131, 1, yes

131, 2, yes

...

300, 1, yes

300, 2, yes

301, 1, no

301, 2, no
```

Could someone point me in the right direction, like: methods that I should look at?

Comment: are you using integers like 130, 131, .., 300 for begin time and end time in your real data set?

Comment: yes I do not have date / datetime types.

Comment: how did you get 301 in the desired data set? is it predefined?

Comment: the time in the desired set is a predefined range (0, to 1000). The desired data should list yes at every t that the interaction was still taking place (in this case from t=130 to t=300).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have the following source DF:

```
In [134]: df
Out[134]:
   begin  end  userA  userB
0    130  134      1      2
1    201  203      5      1
2    333  334      2      5
```

we can do the following:

```
time_range = np.arange(0, 1001)

dfs = []
for u in df[['userA','userB']].stack().unique():
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({'time':time_range,
                             'user':[u] * len(time_range),
                             'interaction': ['no'] * len(time_range)}))
rep = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

for i,r in df.iterrows():
    qry = 'user in {} and {} <= time <= {}'.format([r.userA, r.userB], r.begin, r.end)
    print('Query: [{}]'.format(qry))
    rep.ix[rep.eval(qry), 'interaction'] = 'yes'
```

Output:

```
Query: [user in [1, 2] and 130 <= time <= 134]
Query: [user in [5, 1] and 201 <= time <= 203]
Query: [user in [2, 5] and 333 <= time <= 334]
```

Check:

```
In [133]: rep[rep.interaction == 'yes']
Out[133]:
     interaction  time  user
130          yes   130     1
131          yes   131     1
132          yes   132     1
133          yes   133     1
134          yes   134     1
201          yes   201     1
202          yes   202     1
203          yes   203     1
1131         yes   130     2
1132         yes   131     2
1133         yes   132     2
1134         yes   133     2
1135         yes   134     2
1334         yes   333     2
1335         yes   334     2
2203         yes   201     5
2204         yes   202     5
2205         yes   203     5
2335         yes   333     5
2336         yes   334     5
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! Nice thing you did there with the stack().unique() approach.

Comment: @Bram, glad i could help :)